# Cannot install Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.vsix - “extension not installable on … installed products”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, enterprise-library-6

I click Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.vsix. for Install Enterprise Library config. but It 's can't install this. i need your help please see view install log below

```
**6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -   Supported Products : 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -             Version : [11.0]
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -             Version : [11.0]
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -             Version : [11.0]
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -     References      : 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         -------------------------------------------------------
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Name         : Visual Studio MPF
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Version      : [10.0,)
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         MoreInfoURL  : 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Nested       : No
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Searching for applicable products...
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Integrated)
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - Found installed product - Global Location
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see from the logs it says

Supported Products : 
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Ultimate
6/23/2015 10:45:41 AM -             Version : [11.0]

Version 11 is VS2012, looks like you are tying to install the extension for VS2013 which is Version 12.  You can install the Enterprise library as a nuget package; if you do want to install it as a VS extension then get the one for VS2013

[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsole.V6.VS2013.vsix](https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=9B6A6E6A51692041&resid=9B6A6E6A51692041%21123&authkey=AMBzvwNr0425c_o)

Comment: i am new user. please tell me how to use mark questions ?

Comment: There is a 'tick' icon beside the answer clicking that will mark the question as answered. Also click on the upvote button its above '0'

Comment: and for the VS2015 you can find it here https://randylevy.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/enterpriselibrary-config-for-vs2015/